# bad line length exception in jscape FTPS library

Tags: java, exception, ftps

All,
I am getting this exception

com.jscape.inet.ftp.FtpException: bad line length
 at com.jscape.inet.ftps.FtpsClient.(Unknown Source)
 at com.jscape.inet.ftps.FtpsClient.createUnprotected(Unknown Source)
 at com.jscape.inet.ftps.Ftps$DefaultStrategy.createClient(Unknown Source)
 at com.jscape.inet.ftps.Ftps.connect(Unknown Source)
 at com.jscape.inet.ftps.Ftps.connect(Unknown Source)

while using the library from jscape.Does anybody know what an "bad line length" might be?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), then monitor your network traffic to determine what's actually being transmitted.  Also, try adding your calling code to your question so we can see how you're interfacing with jscape.